# Android studio keeps crashing on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: android, linux

```
 **TERMINAL REPORT**
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 #
 #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000005d30c483, pid=2237, id=0x00007f4c68495700
 # 
 # 



 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b01) (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
 # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.152-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 # Problematic frame:
 # C  0x000000005d30c483
 #
 # Core dump written. Default location: /home/vladimir/android-studio/bin/core or core.2237
 #
 # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 # /home/vladimir/java_error_in_STUDIO_2237.log
 #
 # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 #
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have Oracle JDK 8 installed. I tried thousand and thousands(changing
 xmx,xms, modifing studiovm.options, gradle
      properties...) of solutions, but studio crashes. Please I need help. Thank you.

Comment: did you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **.android** directory in your home folder. Too many upgrades of Android Studio would be causing the unexpected crashes.

Checkout out known issues on **ibus** at http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus